# Qualtrics Javascript - Ignore Custom Validation within the same Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, qualtrics

I am trying to set up a Spot-the-difference game on Qualtrics using Hot Spot question. There is a custom validation in place, so participants are not allowed to proceed to the next puzzle until they have correctly identified the differences. However, I would like to give them an **option to "give up"** and move them to a questionnaire in a separate block.

Illustrative setup:

Block 1 - question 1, Picture Hot Spot question with custom validation; Block 1 - question 2, "Radio choice to Give up"

So by clicking the radio option in Question 2, Custom Validation in Question 1 (within the same block) needs to be ignored. I am guessing this is possible, as in Preview mode, Qualtrics allows users to "tick Ignore Validation" and proceed freely to the next page.

Could anyone help with a **JavaScript** to make this **"Ignore Custom Validation"** within the same question block happen?

Thank you so much!

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is use custom validation to check for either all answers, OR the give up option being selected. Put this all in one question and no validation on the other question on the page.

Comment: Thanks Anthony! It worked!I was looking for a "JavaScript" solution when the simplest solution was actually readily available...

Comment: Not a problem! It is easy to think of a solution, and get caught is one way of thinking when doing things like this!